# How to dismiss a modal view controller by sliding (aka panning) it down?

Tags: ios, ios7, modalviewcontroller, uivewcontroller

I have a modal view controller that I want to be able to dismiss by sliding the view down.  I want it to snap back to the top if I didn't slide it down enough and let go.  How would I go about doing it?

Comment: You should check out the WWDC 2013 video, "Custom Transitions Using View Controllers" (session 218). It talks about interactive transitions, as well as other types of transitions.